# What timezone is Stack Exchange in?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, winterbash

I just got a hat for posting on Christmas and it is still 1 PM on Dec 24th here in Connecticut.

What time zone is Stack Exchange Servers in?

So it is not UTC, and by logic if the server times are correct they are least in the middle of India or east of there as it is now Christmas as of 1:10PM EST

Comment: UTC, I think...

Comment: But even UTC shows 6:09 PM
Monday, December 24, 2012 (UTC)
Time in Coordinated Universal Time as of 1:09PM EST

Comment: Are you suggesting that StackExchange has outsourced to India? :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SE runs on UTC time.

However, the early awarding is [intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159748/174131) according to the devs.  They're giving it out +/- 12 hours from the day listed on the hat.

Comment: You can expand the menu with your name at the top and see the server time